# Are there any tri dimensional chess rules utilising traditional starting positions?

Tags: rules, chess-variants

I have a tri dimensional chess game for my phone which let's the player select different rule sets to play by.
They all start with the king and queen on the attack boards which I find incredibly distasteful.
Is there a rule set which starts the king and queen in the centre positions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for a guy by the name of Larry Smith, he has produced numerous rule sets for tri dimensional chess, although they appear to be directly reverse engineering games played on the Star Trek television series.
The official rules of the World Tri Dimensional Chess Federation start with the king and queen in the centre of the rear rank, flanked by two bishops, with the knights and the rooks assigned to the rear ranks of the attack boards.

Comment: I couldn't find Larry Smith, except on regular chess sites.
I like the World Federation rules though and the starting positions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is this "Kobayashi Maru" variation. It has the classical chess start position.
https://www.chessvariants.com/3d.dir/kobayashimaru.html